# What is the most economical Zerg opening?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Zerg macro openings must balance the timing of:

1. Spawning pool
2. Hatchery at natural expansion
3. Queen

Early spawning pool or hatchery means sacrificing drones to afford it, but means more larva to produce more drones. What is the most economically-optimal build order for Zerg?

Answer (score 1):

The most economical build order for Zerg you can actually play is:

- 9 Overlord
- 15 Hatchery
- 16 Pool
- 17 Gas
- 17 Overlord
- 18 Queen

There might be even more economical ones where you go no gas and 3 Hatcheries instead, but usually this is way too risky.

Comment: Are you sure? With this opening don't you end up with a surplus of minerals, suggesting that earlier queen is necessary for more larvae?

Comment: As mentioned, you can go even more economy, but at some point you get too vulnerable to timing pushes. You have no units to prevent your enemy from scouting. If he sees you do not have any gas (at 17) he will push as soon as he has higher tech units. (Speedlings, cloaked Banshee, 4 Gate etc.) Later gas means later speed and later Lair tech.

Comment: Its not really an earlier queen. It is the standard timing for a queen. Like ayckoster said, you can find more economy but you will get crushed easily.

Comment: Sure it's not 2x Queen? I assume Idra does something similar to this and he often produces two Queens simultaneously.